# Reusing the images for posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing an issue with WordPress gallery post format.
I used this code to get all attached images. It works properly. But when creating a post, it always asks me to upload a new image. I can`t reuse the images already uploaded.
Below is the code I written.

```
<?php
$galleries = get_posts( array(
'post_type' =>  'attachment',
'posts_per_page'    =>  5,
'post_parent'   =>  $post->ID,
) );
if ($galleries) :
foreach ($galleries as $gallery) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="card-img rounded-0" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($gallery->ID); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"></a>
<?php
endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Could you let me know what`s the issue here?

Comment: Hi, misorude, thanks for your response. 

I did not understand what you mean, 
you mean I should use static id? 
instead of $post->id?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean in the first place. _"But when creating a post, it always asks me to upload a new image. I can`t reuse the images already uploaded."_ - what exactly does that mean? Are you unable to find or select them in the  media center, or ...? (If so, what makes you think that had anything to do with the code you have shown?)

Comment: check this screenshot please, http://prntscr.com/lbrvlj this all images are already used in others gallery post. Now I can't create a new gallery post reusing this images. 

I have to re-upload these images then it will appear here. http://prntscr.com/lbrxh6

Comment: _"Now I can't create a new gallery post reusing this images."_ - why, what happens when you try?

Comment: Are you trying to insert a gallery into a normal post here using the default functionality, or is this some sort of custom post type, functionality provided by a plugin, something else ...?

Comment: Mate, Could we make a skype call with screen share please? so i can explain you better. 

skype: tuhin4242

Comment: Nope, the purpose of this site isn't to give private support. And this sounds rather not like an actual programming question in the first place by now, so it is off-topic to begin with.